# Why mysql cannot apply fulltext index when I use two different fulltext index in two different table on the same query?

Tags: mysql, symfony, full-text-search

I have just learn FULL TEXT SEARCH in Mysql because search LIKE '%%' is too slow. I have two tables : user(id, email) ,  user_detail(id, user_id, first_name, last_name).
I created two full text index on these tables :

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD FULLTEXT ftidx_email(email)
```

```
ALTER TABLE user_detail ADD FULLTEXT ftidx_first_name_last_name(first_name,last_name)
```

If I write query like this :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from user u INNER JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id WHERE ( MATCH(u.email) AGAINST('abc@gmail.com' 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE') > 0))
```

In table explain, I see type is fulltext and key is `ftidx_email` => so query is fast.

If I write query like this :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from user u INNER JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id WHERE ( MATCH(ud.fisrt_name, ud.last_name) AGAINST('abc@gmail.com' 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE') > 0))
```

In table explain, I see type is fulltext and key is `ftidx_first_name_last_name`=> so query is fast too.

But if 2 use both fulltext index like this :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from user u INNER JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id WHERE ( MATCH(u.email) AGAINST('abc@gmail.com' 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE') > 0 OR 
MATCH(ud.first_name, ud.last_name) AGAINST('abc@gmail.com' 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE') > 0 )
```

In table explain, I see type is `ALL` and key is `NULL` => so query is slow.

Why Mysql cannot apply two different fulltext index on two different tables in the same query ? Or where am I wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: *Why Mysql cannot apply two different fulltext index on two different tables in the same query ?* Besause of `OR` operatior. Convert `WHERE A OR B` to `WHERE NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)`.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Output is correct , but fulltext index are not used

Comment: Does the query by `user_detail` only uses FT? Check does FTs are used if force them (and does it decreases execution time). Try to use subqueries by separate tables joined in main query, and the same with subquery by one table only.